# `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` in flask api application

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, aiohttp, contextmanager

I'm working on exposing the results of a web scraper through a REST API running on a flask server.

Without going into too much detail, I have the following 2 files that call the same function that scrapes data from a site and returns it as json :

**Working example**

```
# testing_scraper_functions.py

scraper = Scraper(loginparams)


def run_task(task):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    return loop.run_until_complete(task())

# Simulating api call response
def searchChild(eiNumber):
    return run_task(lambda: scraper.searchChild(eiNumber=eiNumber))


childSearchData = searchChild("776105")

scraper.quit()
```

**Broken flask server example**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
port = 5100

if sys.argv.__len__() > 1:
    port = sys.argv[1]


scraper = Scraper(loginparams)

def run_task(task):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    return loop.run_until_complete(task())

@app.route('/api/search_ei/<eiNumber>')
def searchChild(eiNumber):
    return run_task(lambda: hardWorker.searchChild(eiNumber=eiNumber))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port, debug=True)
    scraper.quit()
```

They look like they should work the same but when I do the network request to the API I get the following Runtime Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/Webapp/server.py", line 56, in searchChild
    return run_task(lambda: hardWorker.searchChild(eiNumber=eiNumber))
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/Webapp/server.py", line 39, in run_task
    return loop.run_until_complete(task())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/NYEIS_Scraper/NYEIS_API_V2/NYEIS_Worker.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return await func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/NYEIS_Scraper/NYEIS_API_V2/NYEIS_Worker.py", line 95, in searchChild
    return (await self.searchChilds(eiNumber=eiNumber,
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/NYEIS_Scraper/NYEIS_API_V2/NYEIS_Worker.py", line 70, in searchChilds
    html = await self._htmlFetcher.searchChild(eiNumber=eiNumber)
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/NYEIS_Scraper/NYEIS_API_V2/HTML_Fetcher.py", line 108, in searchChild
    return await (await self._sessionHandler.fetch(method="post", url=url, payload=payload)).text()
  File "/Users/c4q/Desktop/Pycharm Projects/NYEISNYEISBABY/NYEIS_Scraper/NYEIS_API_V2/SessionManager.py", line 56, in fetch
    response = await self._session.post(url=url, headers=self.headers, data=payload)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 466, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 701, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

In the error, `NYEIS_worker` is the Scraper

This scraping function is from an object that has a reference to an aiohttp ClientSession(), which is created when I initialize the object.

The only thing I can even see as a difference is that in the working example I call scraper.quit() which closes the ClientSession(), but I do that in the serverapp too, just after closing the server. **Is the issue that the client session is open too long in the server example?**

Should I create a scraper object and close it on every api request? I feel like this would be a lot slower. Should I reopen the clientsession() on every api call but keep the same scraper object? I'm not sure how to open a session again after closing, I would just be making a new one.

I'm not even sure what a Timeout context manager is. Can I use one without using `async with`? I've written everything using just await and running ClientSession().close() when I'm finished.

Any guidance here is appreciated.

I've kept most of the code out to keep my question shorter, but I can add more snippets if needed